# Duplicate Version for same dependency in maven

Tags: java, maven, multi-module

I am seeing there are multiple version of some dependency are being used in my parent-child module structure for maven, I want to check which are the dependency having different versions defined in different child modules.

Is there any other way to directly find which are those dependency having multiple version defined instead of going each child module dependency manually to check using command **mvn dependency:tree**

As there are multiple child modules there in my project so very hard to find this mismatch. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: it is not directly answering your question but, if your aim is to make sure all child projects are using same version of certain dependency, you could put `dependencyManagement` in your parent project.

Comment: Perhaps this answer can also help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57228180/2513200 (it suggests the maven-enforcer-plugin)

Comment: First `I  am seeing there are multiple version of some dependency are being used ` ... describe/show how you see that? Second if you have the same artifact defined (GroupId/ArtifactId are the same) you should have already WARNING's in your build furthermore it would really help to have the full pom's etc... Also it would be helpful to know which Maven version / plugins versions / JDK versions you are using...

Comment: Its like artifact com.google.guava having different version 30.1.1-jre/28.1.1-jre in different modules - i want to check if there any other dependency being used with multiple versions - Is there any command on maven that can be used to check such scenario's

Comment: My objective here to find the dependency that have multiple version and make them available in the parent pom instead of multiple version in child pom's